# Coloquei um form em um site e não consigo fazer aparecer a mensagem de confirmação. O código está abaixo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hgsubmit() {
if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.nome.value) == false) alert ("Por favor, digite um nome.");
else if (/^\S+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(document.hgmailer.email.value) == false) alert ("Um endereço de e-mail válido é requerido.");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.mensagem.value) == false) alert ("É necessário um conteúdo para mensagem.");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.aluno.value) == false) alert ("É necessário o nome do aluno.");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.responsavel.value) == false) alert ("É necessário o nome do responsável.");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.celularresponsavel.value) == false) alert ("É necessário o Celular do Responsável");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.escolaanterior.value) == false) alert ("É necessário a Escola que cursou em 2017");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.valormensalidade.value) == false) alert ("Valor atual da Mensalidade");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.serie2018.value) == false) alert ("Série que cursará em 2018");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.diahorarioprova.value) == false) alert ("Escolha o dia e horário de sua prova");
else { 
document.hgmailer.submit();
alert ('Obrigado!\n Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.');
}
}
</script>

<------------------------------------------------->

<div class="nicdark_archive1 nicdark_bg_grey nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow">
                <div class="nicdark_textevidence nicdark_bg_orange nicdark_radius_top">
                    <h4 class="white nicdark_margin20">FORMULÁRIO</h4>
                    <i class="icon-mail nicdark_iconbg right medium orange"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="nicdark_margin20">
<form action="http://www.colegiozerohum.com.br/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer" class="nicdark_margin20">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="contatocaio@colegiozerohum.com.br" class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle">


<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Nome do Aluno" name="aluno" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Responsável" name="responsavel" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Telefone residencial" name="Telefone" size="40"><div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Celular do Responsável" name="celular-responsavel" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email do responsável" name="email" size="400">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Escola que cursou em 2017" name="escola-anterior" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Valor atual da Mensalidade" name="valor-mensalidade" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Série que cursará em 2018" name="serie-2018" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_bg_grey2 nicdark_radius nicdark_shadow grey small subtitle" required="required" type="text" value="" placeholder="Escolha o dia e horário de sua prova" name="dia-horario" size="40">
<div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

<input class="nicdark_btn nicdark_bg_orange medium nicdark_shadow nicdark_radius white" type="submit" value="Enviar">

<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.colegiozerohum.com.br/"> 
</form>
 <p style="text-align:right; font-size:14px;">*Trazer Lápis, Borracha e Caneta<br>*Bolsão para alunos que cursarão do 6º ano ao 3º ano do ensino médio</P>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Pra que serve a função `function hgsubmit()` se você não faz nenhuma referência à ela?

Answer (score 1):

Seu código possui muitos problemas. Primeiro, você deve colocar o atributo `onsubmit` na tag `<form>` para chamar a função `hgsubmit()`, caso contrário, a função não tem nenhuma utilidade. Ficaria assim:

```
<form onsubmit="return hgsubmit()" action="http://www.colegiozerohum.com.br/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer" class="nicdark_margin20">
```

Outros erros encontrados foram os nomes de alguns campos do formulário. Por exemplo:

```
name="serie-2018"
```

Evite usar hífen nos nomes dos campos porque vai dá erro nesse tipo de validação do JavaScript:

```
document.hgmailer.serie-2018.value
```

Em vez disso, use: `name="serie2018"`

Seu formulário já possui um botão `type="submit"`, portanto, é desnecessário esta linha na função:

```
document.hgmailer.submit();
```

É preciso também fazer um `return false` em cada `if` para evitar que o `submit` aconteça mesmo se a validação falhar. Por exemplo:

```
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.aluno.value) == false){ alert ("É necessário o nome do aluno."); return false; }
```

Faça isso em cada `if` da função.

Finalmente, corrija na função os nomes dos campos. Verifiquei que alguns nem existem no formulário, como por exemplo: `document.hgmailer.nome.value`. O campo "nome" não existe.

No final, sua função teria esta estrutura:

```
function hgsubmit() {
    if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.nome.value) == false){ alert ("Por favor, digite um nome."); return false; }
    else if (/^\S+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(document.hgmailer.email.value) == false){ alert ("Um endereço de e-mail válido é requerido."); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.mensagem.value) == false){ alert ("É necessário um conteúdo para mensagem."); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.aluno.value) == false){ alert ("É necessário o nome do aluno."); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.responsavel.value) == false){ alert ("É necessário o nome do responsável."); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.celularresponsavel.value) == false){ alert ("É necessário o Celular do Responsável"); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.escolaanterior.value) == false){ alert ("É necessário a Escola que cursou em 2017"); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.valormensalidade.value) == false){ alert ("Valor atual da Mensalidade"); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.serie2018.value) == false){ alert ("Série que cursará em 2018"); return false; }
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.diahorario.value) == false){ alert ("Escolha o dia e horário de sua prova"); return false; }
    else { 
        alert ('Obrigado!\n Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.');
    }
}
```